validation error detected: Value 'PAR1\x15...' at 'table.storageDescriptor.columns.1.member.name' failed to satisfy constraint:
has anybody come across this issue while creating a Glue table which reads data from 'S3'?
'LastCrawl': {'Status': 'FAILED', 'ErrorMessage': "com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value 'PAR1\x15\x04\x15\x1c\x15 L\x15\x02\x15\x04\x00\x00\x0e4' at 'table.storageDescriptor.columns.1.member.name' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD\\uD800\\uDC00-\\uDBFF\\uDFFF\\t]* (Database name: market_stats_monthly_load_beta

I have put data in this below location
s3://datalake/market_stats/fact_state_monthly/v1/parquet/fact_state_monthly/
I can easily read the data using spark shell but while trying to create Redshift external table with some pre-define working mechanism which creates glue table first and then Redhshift table it's throwing the error.
I have also checked regular expression match \[\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD\\uD800\\uDC00-\\uDBFF\\uDFFF\\t\] for each column and random data present in the 'S3' file but I can't see any unmatched stuff.
Not sure what is going on!

This issue has been solved .... it was a script issue generally whenever your data format for the source file is incorrect glue shows this error of regular expression.
